# Checkbox with ajax issue for select or unselect issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I have checkbox code in html below format

```
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="1" data-id="1" class="categorychk" checked="checked">Men                    
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="2" data-id="2" class="categorychk" checked="checked">Women                    
</label>
```

On ajax success response I doing following jquery code it will work fine.

```
$.each(data, function(index,value) {
      $(".categorychk[data-id="+value+"]").attr("checked",true);
});
```

But issue is before call I clear all checked marks and then apply above code. But it does not work.

When I add following code after ajax call

```
$(".categorychk").each(function(){
     $(this).removeAttr("checked");
});
```

> Note : If apply above code without clear checked marks then working fine with the previous checked checkbox.

Comment: Downvoter please comment for down vote. If you do not understand my question then let me ask.

Comment: wasn't me who downvoted...but I'm not entirely clear either. which bit doesn't work, the ".each" loop, or the "clear all checked marks" code (which you haven't shown)?

Comment: Use `.prop` for manipulating _properties_.

Comment: `$(".categorychk[data-id="+value+"]").attr("checked",true);` should be `$(".categorychk[data-id="+value+"]").prop("checked",true);`

Comment: @ADyson When I add `removeAttr` code then do not work above mentioned code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. You're trying to do stuff with attributes, when you should be using properties. Read http://api.jquery.com/attr/, specifically the section entitled "attributes vs properties".

In the meantime, your code will work if you change

```
$(".categorychk").each(function(){
 $(this).removeAttr("checked");
});
```

to

```
$(".categorychk").prop("checked", false);
```

(N.B. you don't need to .each() this, it will operate on all the selected items automatically).

and change

```
$(".categorychk[data-id="+value+"]").attr("checked",true);
```

to

```
$(".categorychk[data-id="+value+"]").prop("checked",true);
```

Note the use of .prop() instead of .attr()

Comment: Thank you @ADyson I used `.prop` and solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

As documented in [how do i check uncheck a checkbox input or radio button](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-check-uncheck-a-checkbox-input-or-radio-button/) you need to use jQuery prop:

```
$(".categorychk[data-id="+value+"]").prop('checked', true);
```

And to filter elements by data-id you can use:

```
$(".categorychk").filter(function() {
      return $(this).data('id') == value;
});
```

Comment: This code work fine But when I put `removeAttr` code before this line then it do not work.

Comment: Thank you @gaetanoM I used `.prop` and solved